# Salesforce apex rest api url not found

Tags: apex, httprequest, http

I'm looking to send JSON data to external system using Apex. However, this data does not belong to any specific SObject but it is some logic and mainly passes along metadata. I have an Apex Class I'm trying to expose it as a REST API with HTTPGET. Does Salesforce allow such apex classes? If yes, what am I doing wrong here?

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getMyInfo')
global with sharing class myApexClass {
    @HttpGet
    global static String retrieveAllInfoNecessary() {
        //do some logic and build json string to return
    }
}
```

However, when I try it using Workbench, I'm getting 404 error
Under Rest Explorer, I set method to "GET" and URL as: `/services/apexrest/api/getMyInfo`

Error Message: Could not find a match for URL
Error Code: NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

including `/api/` in your url is incorrect.

The endpoint is just `/services/apexrest/<your url mapping here>`
so you should be making requests to `/services/apexrest/getMyInfo`, in your particular example.

This is corroborated by [the documentation on the `@RestResource` annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm) (part of the general Apex developer guide documentation).